# Wicket: stateless AJAX behaviors in stateful page without serialization

Tags: java, wicket, behavior, stateless, stateful

I have pretty stateful page with plenty of AJAX components. Most of these components have behaviors, which renders JavaScript code for calling AJAX requests to Java code. Because page isn't stateless, each request causes serialization of page. So far so good.

But some of these AJAX requests doesn't change page ever, so serialization of page isn't necessary. For example it is forward caching data for (home-brewed) datagrid component. These requests are calling continuously and serialization of page during each request causes delays.

There are some projects for stateless wicket components out there, e.g. [wicket-stateless](http://code.google.com/p/jolira-tools/), but it solves another situation -- request of stateless components are processed on new instances of stateless pages. I want to process requests on existing stateful page instance but without serialization.

I have tried to implement this in my own `RequestCycleProcessor.resolve()`, but I hung on searching for page from requestParameters because `Session.getPage()` always **touches page and it causes serialization** after request processing.

- Is there any example, idea, whatever for implementing this in Wicket?

Hope it's understandable :)

Comment: I also want to do this.  I have it so the unique id for the component with this AJAX behavior can give my code all the "state" information it needs on the callback.  The unique id can be accessed using `AjaxRequestTarget.getLastFocusedElementId()`.  But I did not yet figure out how to prevent the page from refreshing.

Comment: I found the same issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes rather deeply into wicket, you might want to consider asking it on the mailinglists ( http://wicket.apache.org/community.html#Community-Mailinglists )

Comment: Happened. So far without success, maybe my English isn't as good as it should.